# How to get textArea content

Tags: grails

How would I get a hold of what's in a `<g:textArea>` on a GSP so I can send it to my controller as a param? I thought it would already be in the default param Map since its on my GSP with an id of "comments".

I tried:

```
document.getElementsByName('comments').value
```

and

```
$('#comments').value
```

in the Chrome dev tools JS console but keep getting undefined with text in there.

Comment: Read the docs for `getElementsByTagName`, it doesn't return a DOM element.

Comment: @Evan Trimboli Can you provide link to this exact DOC? Thanks.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByTagName

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In its simplest form, you have something like this in your gsp:

```
<g:form name="form" action="target">
    <g:textArea name="text"/>
    <g:submitButton name="Submit"/>
</g:form>
```

When you press the submit button it will call the `target` action on the form controller. There you can access the text via the `text` property (name of the textarea) from the standard  `params` object.

```
def target () {
    render params.text
}
```